# tangent line of a parametric curve in the form y = mx + c

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric

so for `x(t) = 5cos(2t), y(t) = t^(7/2), and t = pi/4`

i need to find the tangent line at point t=pi/4 in the form y=mx+c
it is my understanding that

`dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)`
and `m = dy/dx`

however when i evaluate dy/dx, and find y = (Pi/4)^(7/2), my answer appears to not be correct, i double checked on this calculator (which i know is likely to be unreliable) and my logic was the same, here is the [link](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/tangent-line-calculator/?ft=t&f=5+cos+%282t%29&g=t%5E%287%2F2%29&px=pi+%2F4&steps=on).

i only include it so you can see the working out as i dont know how to format well on this site yet and dont want to create an eyesore. I however came to the same answer, the same derivatives, and the same value for `y when t = pi/4`, and i have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: i'd like to stress i did the working out myself first, not just took the answer from the calculator, the fact that mine is the same as the calculator makes me more worried about my logic then secure.

Comment: MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future reference.

Comment: @JohnLou thank you, i intend to get familar with that soon.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: I've graphed the function and the derivative [here](http://imgur.com/a/gQ20p). This looks like what you got, so I'm not sure where you made a mistake.

Comment: @JohnLou, because it is an online submission for the answer, and putting in my answer both in the approximate decimal form, or the formula form spits out wrong.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mj5zoda6mo) a live link. You are right, so maybe you're missing the negative sign?

Comment: @JohnLou you are right i missed the minus sign! i would give u the answer but unfortunately u answered through comment form so i cant :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=5 \cos (2 t)\implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\color{red}{-}10 \sin (2 t)$$
$$y=t^{7/2}\implies \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{7 }{2}t^{5/2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt} }{\frac{dx}{dt} }=-\frac{7}{20} t^{5/2} \csc (2 t)$$ So,  $$t=\frac \pi 4\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{7 \pi ^{5/2}}{640}$$ Now, write the equation of the tangent as $$y-y_0=y'\,(x-x_0)$$ Using $x_0=0$ and $y_0=\frac{\pi ^{7/2}}{128}$ makes $$y=-\frac{7 \pi ^{5/2}}{640}\,x+\frac{\pi ^{7/2}}{128}$$ which, in decimal form, would write $$y=0.429353 -0.191334\, x$$

Comment: yeah, thats what i originally got, but i missed the minus sign which ended up in me questioning my logic, careless mistakes causing frustration!

Comment: @Darko. If every single time I missed a sign, I was given a dime, I should be a millionaire ! Cheers.